# WP-PageNavi plugin doesn't work with multiple pages of search results

Tags: plugins, search, pages

I'm using [Dilectio theme](http://designdisease.com/portfolio/dilectio_wordpress_theme/) and [WP-PageNavi plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/). The plugin creates links to multiple pages perfectly on every page except for the search results page.

For example, when I search for the keyword "lamp," it indicates there are 2 pages of search results. When I click on page 2, it takes me to page 2 of my blog, not page 2 of the search results. Can someone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the problem was in my theme's searchform.php file. I changed the form method from "post" to "get." Now search queries show up in the url address.
Before:
`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">`
After:
`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">`
Problem solved.

Comment: Use `echo esc_url( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; );`. See [Data Validation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation).

Answer (score 0):

Dilectio theme comes with an old version of WP-PageNavi plugin embedded in its functions.php file, so the best thing you can do is just remove the `wp_pagenavi` function form the functions.php, install the plugin and you should be set.

Comment: I just checked the demo of the theme and searched for 'the' and the same thing happens.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it seems I already did that. The old version is missing from the functions.php file, and the newest version of WP-PageNavi is installed and activated on my plugins page. Hmmm. Now what?

Comment: Can you post a url to search results?

Comment: Nope. That must be the problem. The url for search results comes up as a generic http://www.craftynest.com/index.php  So, the plugin isn't the problem, the theme is, correct?

Comment: Thank you, Bainternet! I wouldn't have figured it out without you.