# Page 2 of Search Results shows homepage

Tags: search, pages, forms

Search bar is just under the header and menu at the top of the page.

Example search: http://www.animefushigi.com/?s=bleach

Scroll down and try going to page 2, see it shows homepage instead.

[Similar problem here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14927/wp-pagenavi-plugin-doesnt-work-with-multiple-pages-of-search-results), but the answer in that question did not work for me

I believe the issue is with my searchform.php.

I have pasted my searchform and search.php here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rSedK6AC

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the `$paged` arguments

```
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Comment: where does that go

Comment: I believe it should be right above the loop.

Comment: another thing Chrome is giving a malware warning about your site. You may want to check it out.

Comment: Yes that issue has been handled. And that should go above the loop in which file,  the search.php  ?

Comment: great... I am glad it worked for you..

Comment: No I mean the malware warning issue is fixed.  this question still not solved

Answer (score 0):

Edit your index.php file.
Insert the $paged statement immediately prior to your post query.  So something like this:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$recent = new WP_Query("showposts=10&paged=" . $paged); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
```

Comment: Well my index.php does not need paging. But I tried your suggestion, and now the only difference is that it shows page 2 of the homepage instead of page 1. Index.php is not the problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.  I needed to recreate the query arguments based on the querystring.  I wasn't able to find another way to do it.

Insert the following before the loop.

```
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode( "&", $query_string );
$search_query = array();

foreach( $query_args as $key => $string ) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} // foreach

$search_query['posts_per_page'] = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
$search_query['paged'] = $page;

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $search_query );
```

What I'm essentially doing is pulling down the entire querystring, parsing each key/value pair, and inserting into a new wp_query argument list.  I'm also setting the paging parameters of the argument list separately.

Comment: Ahem … [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)? :)

Answer (score 0):

It's 2020 and I still had the same issue. Didn't find a solution anywhere; posting it here in case it helps someone else.

I solved the problem by editing .htaccess. In my particular case, this was messing things up:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```